# Can I summon Interplanetarypurplythorny Dragon using Witch of the Black Forest's effect

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Just wondering if this is a legal use of the card's effects since IPPT Dragon's effect does state that when a monster on my side of field is destroyed I can special it. Considering that my card being destroyed is Witch of the Black Forest, and that the card I choose using Witch's effect is IPPT dragon, would I be able to special IPPT Dragon? 
I know Witch is a banned card, this is for my own personal duels.

IPPT= Interplanetarypurplythorny

Comment: I like the name Interplanetarypurplythorny Dragon!   Interplanetarypurplythorny!!   Interplanetarypurplythorny!! It's a nice name, does anyone else think so?

Comment: i hate using cards with long names in tournaments, tiny box to write down the card name, i hate bags of fun writing *Number 38: Hope Harbinger Dragon Titanic Galaxy* down... not

Comment: @WhatsThePoint don't forget [Number 81: Superdreadnought Rail Cannon Super Dora](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Number_81:_Superdreadnought_Rail_Cannon_Super_Dora), it's double Super, so it's double Nice :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will not be able to get the Interplanetarypurplythorny Dragon from the effect of Witch of the Black Forest's and activate its effect.

This is because the last thing to happen isn't a monster being destroyed but rather a monster being added to hand.

If you already had Interplanetarypurplythorny Dragon in your hand and Witch of the Black Forest is being destroyed, you still retain the priority to activate an effect after the mandatory effect of Witch of the Black Forest goes on the chain.

Comment: Note that in the second case (IPPT in hand when Witch is destroyed), both effects will form a Chain because they have the same triggering condition. This has nothing to do with (retaining) Priority (and never had).

Comment: Change the word priority for ability. The definition is still the same. You have an OPTIONAL effect and a MANDATORY effect that you can activate. (IPPT is optional whereas Witch of the Black Forest is MANDATORY.) Priority still applies because your opponent can cut in with an effect if its their turn.

Comment: Well, no, they can't, that's my point. Witch takes chain link 1 because it's mandatory, Dragon takes chain link 2 because it's optional (if it's activated). THEN the opponent can activate stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot activate 2 effects at once and when the dragon is in your hand, your witch will already be in the graveyard and you can't summon your dragon then. So my the answer is no.

Comment: I'm a little bit sceptical of that ruling (which is not to say it's wrong, mind you) - it only confirms that the Witch can search out IPPT Dragon, which is fairly obvious; not whether the Dragon can then be special summoned following the search.  So it doesn't feel like the ruling affects the specific issue at hand, necessarily.  Plus, it's a wiki with no restrictions on who can edit (as far as I can tell) - difficult to judge the reliability of the source...